# Wiris editor missing icons when used in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, editor, wiris

I am trying to use the Wiris mathematics editor within a React component. I am initialising the editor within the "componentDidMount" function:

```
componentDidMount() {
 var script = document.createElement("script");
 script.src = "https://www.wiris.net/demo/editor/editor";

 var callback = function() {
    var editor = com.wiris.jsEditor.JsEditor.newInstance({
        language: "en"
        });

     editor.insertInto(document.getElementById("editorContainer"));
 };

 script.onload = callback;

 document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

However when the editor gets rendered it has an issue where many of the symbols are missing. See below:

[image]

I am not sure what is causing this issue. Is it because of the way I am referencing the external script, or is it an issue with the way that React is rendering the content?

I've recreated the issue in a CodePen [here](https://codepen.io/BenSmith/pen/bRzvJE/).

Note that if you open that CodePen in Chrome (Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)) or IE 11 (11.0.14393.0) you will see the problem. However it does appear to work in Firefox 54.0.1.

Comment: Unfortunately, we haven't been able to reproduce the issue in the CodePen sample you provide. The way you are calling the script is correct.

Comment: @WIRISMATHsupportteam If you open that code pen in Chrome (Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)) or IE 11 (11.0.14393.0) you will see the problem. However it does appear to work in Firefox 54.0.1.

Comment: We can see that commenting the reset.min.css in Chrome works too. We have passed this on to our development team so they can investigate further and eventually prevent this behaviour for similar reset CSS.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I can confirm that if I disable the rules set by reset.min.css the Wiris editor gets rendered correctly. Looking forward to seeing a fix for this issue!

Comment: This issue is fixed on our latest WIRIS EDITOR release.

Comment: @WIRISMATHsupportteam That is great news.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wiris developers fixed this issue in Nov '17.

I've left the question open as the CodePen might be useful to React developers investigating Wiris!